# Mozilla build firefox 3.5.1 on Ubuntu issues with images going greyscale, and javascript not running

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, repository, grayscale

I got bored of waiting for them to update the version of firefox-3.5 in the repos (currently 3.5 RC2) to one of the final builds, so I downloaded 3.5.1 from mozilla.com and extracted it to a folder on my desktop.

Then I changed my firefox shortcuts from `/usr/bin/firefox %u` to `/home/me/Desktop/firefox/firefox %u` . However since I have done this, I've noticed a few problems:

- Some images (including parts of the UI) are being rendered in greyscale
- Some javascript does not run. No errors, no anything, it just doesn't run.

Has anyone else encountered these problems, and know of a possible fix? I've tried disabling all add-ons, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this on bugzilla, and this comment:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507600#c2

> Does it work if you change gfx.color_management.mode from 2 to 0 in
>   about:config ?

solved it.

Comment: I had to restart my PC before I saw the changes take effect.. not sure why.  But I'm grateful for the answer!!!